# How to get the new color value from Input Color after choosing it?

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I use Input Color to change the color of the text in a table cell.

I can select the cell, click on the color button, select the color and press enter (on Chrome).

My **problem is** that the color changes only after I press again on the color button (and the window open again..).

How to change/get the value of the element after selecting the new color without clicking on it again ?

Is this related to the **EventListener** I use for the Input Color ?

I need to use JavaScript for this, **no jQuery**.

Comment: How about `change` listener ? Edit: `<input type="color" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000" onchange='alert()'>`

Comment: @RayonDabre I added 'this.inputC.onchange='alert()';' and tried to see if it detects the value changes with 'function alert() { alert("Changed");}'. No detection at all. The value changes only after I close the color chooser and I click again the button.

Comment: better with some code JS fiddle

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get input value with onchange event.

```js
jQuery('#color').on('change',function(){
 jQuery('#choosen-color').text(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" id="color">
<div id="choosen-color"></div>
```

UPDATE

```js
document.getElementById('color').onchange=function(){
 // do whatever you want with value
  alert(this.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color">
```

Comment: "I need to use JavaScript for this, no jQuery."

Comment: @ZimSystem, added update to answer with pure javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try This code it is work foe me..!

**This code is pure JavaScript not use jquery..!**

Use This Code And Enjoy...

```js
var color1= document.getElementById("color1");
var rescolor1= document.getElementById("res_color1");
  color1.addEventListener("input", function() {
    res_color1.innerHTML = color1.value;
  }, false); 
var color2= document.getElementById("color2");
var res_text_color = document.getElementById("res_color2");
  color2.addEventListener("input", function() {
    res_color2.innerHTML = color2.value;
  }, false); 
// mmm.... is it an Opera bug? the manual input doesn't fire the input event type. (works just like change)
```

```html
    color 1: <input type="color" name="color1" id ="color1" required=""> <span id="res_color1"></span><br><br>
    color 2: <input type="color" name="color2" id ="color2" required=""> <span id="res_color2"></span><br><br>
```